# Trouble with window.open

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document instanceof HTMLDocument //evaluates to false//
```

Why is this evaluating to false, and how can I make it evaluate to true?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When I call window.open('http://stackoverflow.com'); it still evaluates to false..

Comment: Try http:// before the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *document* must exist; if you're trying to access it before it exists, of course it will not be an instance of anything. Otherwise `HTMLDocument` is not the *HTMLDocument* that you want to check that `newWindow.document` is an `instanceof`, you actually want to test against `newWindow.HTMLDocument`

```
newWindow.document instanceof HTMLDocument;           // false
newWindow.document instanceof newWindow.HTMLDocument; // true
```